# Cannot get v-simple-checkbox or v-checkbox to render the box itself

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am following the documentation's example for [creating a data table with a checkbox in one column](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#simple-checkbox).

While everything else is rendering fine, the checkbox itself will not show up.  The animations from clicking it show up, but not the box itself.  This is also the case with `v-checkbox` in the `New Item` modal/dialog.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:
[image]

I have tried manually specifying the Vuetify CDN in my `index.html`, but that had no effect.  Using developer tools, I've ensured that Vuetify's CSS is being loaded and applied to the page.

Here's my simplified table component:

```html
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="workorders"
    :items-per-page="5">
    <template v-slot:top>
      <v-toolbar
        flat
      >
        <v-toolbar-title>Work Orders</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-dialog
          v-model="dialog"
          max-width="500px"
        >
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-btn
              color="primary"
              dark
              class="mb-2"
              v-bind="attrs"
              v-on="on"
            >
              New Item
            </v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-card>

            <v-card-text>
              <v-container>
                <v-row>
                    <v-checkbox
                      v-model="editedItem.sameAsCustomerAddress"
                      label="Same as Customer Address?"
                      @click="editedItem.sameAsCustomerAddress = !editedItem.sameAsCustomerAddress"
                    ></v-checkbox>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-container>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-toolbar>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
      <v-icon
        small
        class="mr-2"
        @click="editItem(item)"
      >
        mdi-pencil
      </v-icon>
      <v-icon
        small
        @click="deleteItem(item)"
      >
        mdi-delete
      </v-icon>
    </template>
     <template v-slot:[`item.status`]="{ item }">
       <v-chip
       :color="getStatus(item.status).color"
       dark>
       {{ getStatus(item.status).status }}
       </v-chip>
     </template>
     <template v-slot:[`item.hasPaid`]="{ item }">
       <v-simple-checkbox
       v-model="item.hasPaid">
       </v-simple-checkbox>
     </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `v-data-table` expects the `value` field to be **lowercase** even if the actual field is mixed case:

```js
{ text: 'Paid?', value: 'hasPaid' },  // ❌ `hasPaid` must be lowercase
{ text: 'Paid?', value: 'haspaid' },  // ✅
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QWGKKby?editors=1010)

Comment: Is this by design? I consider this to be a bug to be honest, because it is quite unexpected. Other column/field types do not behave this way, so why should boolean/checkbox fields be different?

Comment: @JohanvanTonder I agree it seems like a bug.